# How to expose a property (virtual field) on a Django Model as a field in a TastyPie ModelResource

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

I have a property in a Django Model that I'd like to expose via a TastyPie ModelResource.

My Model is

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    _genderChoices = ((u"M", u"Male"), (u"F", u"Female"))

    user = Models.OneToOneField(User, editable=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices = _genderChoices)

    def _get_full_name(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

    fullName = property(_get_full_name)
```

My ModelResource is

```
class UserProfileResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = models.UserProfile.objects.all()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        fields = ['gender', 'fullName']
```

However all I'm currently getting out of the tastypie api is:

```
{
    gender: 'female',
    resource_uri: "/api/v1/userprofile/55/"
}
```

I have tried playing with the fields property in the ModelResource, but that hasn't helped. Would love to understand what is going on here.

Comment: don't miss the 'u' :return u"%s %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should be able to define it as a [field](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-tastypie/en/latest/fields.html?highlight=fields) try:

```
class UserProfileResource(ModelResource):
    fullname = fields.CharField(attribute='_get_full_name', readonly=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = models.UserProfile.objects.all()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        fields = ['gender',]
```

**Edit**

You also have to include: `set readonly=True` on your `CharField`, or TastyPie will try to set its value on insertion or update.

Comment: there is a way to order by this field?

Answer (score 3):

A full example with dehydrate:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    fullname = fields.CharField(readonly=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = auth_models.User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'

    def dehydrate_fullname(self, bundle):
        return u"{first_name} {last_name}".format(
            first_name=bundle.obj.first_name, last_name=bundle.obj.last_name)
```