# TastyPie and properties

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

If I have a django model with django fields and some properties called by property() function, can tastypie interact with this virtual fields? Or I have to include logic into tastypie's dehydrate, obj_create, obj_update function?

Model:

```
class A (models.Model):
    x = models.CharField()
    def get_y(self):
        return self.x
    def set_y(self, value):
        self.y = value
    y = property(get_y, set_y)
```

Can resources be as short as:

```
class AResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = A.objects.all()
        fields = ['id','x','y']
```

Or should it be as long as:

```
class AResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = A.objects.all()
        fields = ['id','x','y']

def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['y'] = bundle.obj.x
    return bundle


def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    bundle.obj.y = bundle.data['y']
    bundle = super(AResource, self).obj_create(
        bundle,
        request,
    )

    return bundle

def obj_update(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    bundle = super(AResource, self).obj_update(
        bundle,
        request,
    )
    bundle.obj.y = bundle.data['y']
    return bundle
```

If it could be short then what would be x equal if I pass x = 1, y = 2 by tasypie?

Answer (score 1):

If you want fields on a resource that come from methods, you can include something like this:

```
method_field = fields.CharField(attribute='my_method')
```

Comment: Is it duplicated?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078035/how-to-expose-a-property-virtual-field-on-a-django-model-as-a-field-in-a-tasty